# Using auto versus typedef for lambda inside asio reactor

Tags: sockets, c++11, lambda, boost-asio

I have some code like this:

```
typedef std::function<void (void)> const& basic_callback_t;

void Receive::async_basic(fragmenting_socket& socket, const ID id, basic_callback_t fn)
{
int buffer[1024];
socket.async_receive(buffer, sizeof(buffer), [&](const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bytes)
{
    ....

    if (fn) 
    {
        fn(); 
    } else
    {
        THROW("async_receive callback: Could not call fn()");
    }
});

}
```

and `socket.async_receive()` is calling `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::async_receive_from()`

I am calling `async_basic()` with this code:

```
boost::asio::io_service m_service;
fragmenting_socket m_camera_socket { m_service, 0, 0 };

std::thread service_thread([&] { m_service.run(); });

bool finished = false;
// NOTE: this is weird, when I correctly define f as basic_callback_t, it works.
// when I use "auto f" or keep the lambda anonymous, then it gets invalidated inside the asio reactor
protocol::basic_callback_t f = [&finished] ()
{
    finished = true;
};

protocol::Receive::async_basic(m_camera_socket, protocol::ID::QUERY, f);
```

The code above seems to work ok and `f` gets called and finished is set to true. However, if I pass an anonymous lambda into `async_basic` or declare `f` as

```
auto f = [&] () ....
```

then the asio reactor treats `fn` inside `async_receive` as out of scope and the `THROW()` statement is called. Does anyone know why this might be happening? I'm actually confused as to why specifically declaring `f` as a `protocol::basic_callback_t` works and declaring it as `auto` does not. In both cases, the functor is placed on the stack and should be out of scope in the thread that `m_service` is running in.

I'm compiling with g++ 4.8.2 with the -std=c++11 flag set and -fPIC.

Cheers
Ben

Answer (score 2):

In both variations you have [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

```
void Receive::async_basic(fragmenting_socket& socket, const ID id, basic_callback_t fn)
{
    int buffer[1024];
    socket.async_receive(buffer, sizeof(buffer), [&](const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bytes)
    {
        if (fn) {
            fn(); 
        } else {
            THROW("async_receive callback: Could not call fn()");
        }
});
```

The call to `async_receive` captures `fn` *by reference*. However, the reference becomes invalid as soon as `async_basic` returns.

**The same applies for `buffer[]`** as a matter of fact: `buffer` goes out of scope so you have Undefined Behaviour whan `async_receive` writes to it.

The nature of UB is that anything can happen, which explains why you appear to see different behaviours.

Comment: So how do I put fn on the heap so it doesn't go out of scope?
Thanks! Ben

Comment: The usual pattern is to have a `enable_shared_from_this` class representing the connection/transmission sequence. That class can then own the buffers (and other things like state). For the completion handler you don't need to do special things, just _don't_ capture the `function<>` by reference

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is there an example of this that you can point me to? I looked up enable_shared_from_this and it is a way to pass shared_ptrs of the class. I guess the safest thing is to create a functor instead of a lambda, create one on the heap and pass it around....

Comment: Many of my answers show this. In fact, my latest answer in [tag:boost-asio] had a very similar discussion and [I ended up linking  to some](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75267/discussion-between-joe-and-sehe). Here's a search to get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+%5Bboost-asio%5D+is%3Aanswer+shared_from_this

Comment: Thanks. I got it by
    socket.async_receive(buffer, sizeof(buffer), [&buffer,id,fn](const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bytes) {....

I passed the std::function by value and it worked. The buffer is still not correct but at least it's not a blocker. It's weird to think that every lambda closure is going to require smart pointers and careful passing by value instead of by reference in order to preserve correctness.

Comment: The buffer is a blocker. UB will snuff your pet dog and eat an airplane for lunch. The fact that it appears to work is no solace. **This** is why C++ has the reputation of allowing you to blow your foot off. Do not play fast and loose with Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: About the correctness and smartpointers, I agree (managed languages achieve this by always garbage collecting any object...). However, often you can often manage the lifetime in some other fashion. E.g. [in this sample](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22695083#22695083) I used a simple class-local instead of function local. Just be aware that your connections/transmissions aren't re-entrant that way.

Comment: To avoid issues with buffer, I did the simple thing and did a static new: static int* buffer = new int[1]; and then simplified the async_receive to 
socket.async_receive(buffer, sizeof(int), [id,fn](const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bytes). 
Everything seems to work. I justify the static new because it's not going to be used anywhere else and the lambda is the absolute last thing to be called in the async_receive sequence.

Comment: By the way, it's too bad that boost::asio doesn't implement RTP or some kind of udp packet reassembly. I had to build my own packet assembler which was really a pain in the butt and I'm sure there's bugs in it. I wish that someone would build an asio fragmenting/reassembling udp socket. I'd submit my own but I have no idea who to talk to...